# Pass by value and memory consumption in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pass-by-value

Let's say I got this code:

```
function MinMax(list) {
  const min = Math.min(...list);
  const max = Math.max(...list);

  return {
    min,
    max,
    list,
  };
}

const massiveList = [
  1,
  // supposedly a gazillion
  // integer values
  10000000,
];

const minMax = MinMax(massiveList);

const minMaxList = minMax.list;

console.log('min              ', minMax.min);
console.log('max              ', minMax.max);
console.log('minMaxList length', minMaxList.length);
```

Here's my question: since arguments are passed by value in JavaScript, does that mean, that after that point in code, where *minMax.list* is assigned to *minMaxList*, three copies of the original *massiveList* exist in heap memory?

Comment: no. you have only one large array and a reference to it.

Comment: But e.g. here https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/ it says "In JavaScript, all function arguments are always passed by value. It means that JavaScript copies the values of the variables into the function arguments." So, there must exist at least two copies of the array. Not sure about the third though.

Comment: no. in javascript, only primitive values are handed over by value. all other, like array (still objects), object, and functions are handed over by reference. you can proof it by yourselt by changing the array after handing over to function and change a value inside of the function. the outer array (the original reference) has the same change.

Comment: Apparently yes. Spread operator creates new array out of inital one and accordingly to unpredictable nature of garbage collector you'll have up to 3 different copies of your massive array.

Comment: @Jaood_xD, i am not sure, if an implementation of a spreading into a paramter list generates an array, or just iterates the values and consume the values while iterating.

Comment: @NinaScholz, reflecting on change doesn't seem to proof the uniqueness of the object (i.e. arrary). If you take a look at the article I've mentioned previously (almost at the end) upon change a second object (in this case resulting in creating an additional array) would be created.

Comment: @NinaScholz it is. Have done a quick script with checking `process.memoryUsage().heapUsed` out and inside the function  `function f(...arr)`. It rises every time I call this `f` with spreading array into params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below demo with reference value

```js
const massiveList = [
  1,
  // supposedly a gazillion
  // integer values
  10000000,
];

const testReference = (list) => {
   console.log(list === massiveList) //true
}

testReference(massiveList)
```

In your case, `list` and `massiveList` are the same reference which means any modification on `list` will be applied on `massiveList` as well.

`...list` means you've cloned the original list to another list that will be allocated newly in the memory.

The below demo is to show reference values get changed for the new list, so that's why the result is `false`

```js
const massiveList = [
  1,
  // supposedly a gazillion
  // integer values
  10000000,
];

const testReference = (list) => {
  const newList = [...list]
  console.log(list === newList) //false
}

testReference(massiveList)
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered checking on object equality. That's a pretty simple and and elegant solution to find out about object "incarnations".